# Loop through all available OLAP cube filter values

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, data-cube

Tried to find a solution here, but was not successful.

I have a pivot table in Excel, which is connected to a data cube. What works is setting filters on values inside the `Pivot Table` with the code:

```
ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields(fieldOrder_two).VisibleItemsList _
= Array(tempArray)
```

I receive an error message if a value being filtered is not existing - which makes sense.

Is there a way to obtain a list of all available values before setting the filter? It would be nice to populate an array with the `ItemsList`, but I can't find a ways to "talk" to the `itemslist`.

Example of the available values:

[image: available values]

Edit: I would like to avoid an Error Handling solution, because I would need to perform other checking (Upper/Lower Case) as well probably.

Comment: I got the same problem, I need to set filters but I don't know if they are present so it crashes. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: unfortunately no :(